# Configuring crosstool-NG for ReadyNAS Duo v2

Tags: linux, debian, nas

I would like to create a toolchain for my NAS, which is not supported any more by Netgear. It has a Debian "squeeze" operating system, which doesn't allow me to install stuff any more (no `apt-get install` command seems to work).

The NAS in question is the "ReadyNAS Duo v2", updated to the latest possible version named "RAIDiator-arm-5.3.12".

Some facts I managed to figure out about it:

- CPU architecture: ARMv5TE, 32bit, little endian
- Kernel version: `2.6.21.8.duov2` (from `uname -r`)
- Debian version: `6.0.3` (from `lsb_release -a`)
- glibc version: `2.11.2` (from `ldd --version`)
- gcc version: `4.4.5` (from `gcc -v`)
- binutils: `2.20.1` (from `ld -v`)

I read about crosstool-NG, installed it and was getting ready to configure it. But the available options in the `tc-ng menuconfig` do not match the version numbers of my system. For example, the earliest available kernel  for the target OS is 2.6.32.68 (I assume that I need 2.6.21.8), or for `glibc` there is `2.11.1` and `2.12.1` but not `2.11.2` which I need, etc.

I also wonder if I should make sure the version numbers of the *companion tools* and *libraries* also match. For the Kernel version, there is also the option *use custom tarball or directory*, which I'm not sure if it's intended as a fallback option in case the precise version number is not available.

I'm using the instructions on [crosstool-ng.org](http://crosstool-ng.org/#download_and_usage) but there are no details about the configuration (it only says "Simply fill in specific values in the adequate options."). Other tutorials, such as [2](http://nairobi-embedded.org/040_using_crosstool-ng.html#phase-2-toolchain-configuration-build-and-install) weren't more specific either.

So the question is what can I do to correctly configure crosstool-NG for my specific figure given these obstacles?

Comment: BTW, [the Debian Archive](https://archive.debian.net/squeeze/) still has squeeze packages available, in case that helps.

Comment: You are right, dirkt, I updated the sources.list with the archive urls, but it turns out I have another problem I [posted here on the unix&linux stack exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/336831/210048). The underlying purpose  is to install **ffmpeg**